# Multiple (separate/namespaced) Meteor client codebases per single Meteor app

Tags: meteor

I'm working on rewriting an existing application with Meteor that has two fairly distinct use cases (an administrator account and user account). Both could be considered separate apps in terms of functionality, but share the same back end database.

Is there any way to "namespace" or otherwise define separate clients so that Meteor only packages and sends assets for the client that's being accessed. For ie. the `meteor-router` could push different clients for the `/admin*` space and the `/user*` space, that way there's no unnecessary overhead downloaded for either client.

I expect this is outside the scope of what's within the means of a Meteor smart package like `meteor-router`.

Comment: Seems related to this unanswered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357394/where-to-put-a-separate-admin-interface-for-a-meteor-app?rq=1

Comment: I'm also interested in this and found no solution so far. That question pasted above now has an answer based on iron-router but I think that doesn't solve the problem of shipping packages only to specific applications. Will keep looking, hoping the "multiple meteor apps with shared database" approach is not the only way to go :-/

Comment: The only solution I've found so far is kind of hackish, but helps reduce the "packaging everything" overhead. If there's a part of my app that uses a script or template that doesn't need to be shared with the rest of the app I include it at run time with the [external-file-loader](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/external-file-loader) package. Throw those assets in a static folder like `public` and this handles the AJAX calls and loading. Coupled with [session-extras](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/session-extras) you can trigger things when loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create two applications that connect to the same database. Shared server code may be put in a package and included in both, so there will be no need to repeat it.

Comment: True, I guess I was hoping there'd be an easier way to "sandbox" the separate clients without incurring the extra overhead of two separate apps.